# Using the Laplace transform to solve an ODE with piecewise input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

[image]

I have the answer to this problem. My question is with the function $u(t)$. $u(t)$ is:

$$u(t) = 2\cos(t)+2\sin(t-\pi/2)*1(t-\pi/2)$$

Why is there a $1(t-\pi/2)$ multiplying the $2\sin(t-\pi/2)$? Wouldn't $u(t) = 2\cos(t)+2\sin(t-\pi/2)$ suffice for $ u(t)$? $1(t-\pi/2)$ is a step function right? What's that got to do with a $\sin$?
I'm very confused about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\cos(t) + \sin(t-\pi/2) = 0$ and $\sin$ is needed to take effect after the point $\pi/2$ to obtain the given graphic. Hence it is multiplied by $1(t-\pi/2)$ which is the unit step function as you correctly guessed.

In other words you need to obtain

$$u(t)=\begin{cases} \cos(t) & 0<t<\pi/2 \\ 0 & \pi/2 \leq t \end{cases}$$

and remember the definition of step function.

Comment: so your saying if 1(t-pi/2) wasn't there, my function actually is 0 for all t > 0? So the step function essentially tells the sine to take effect after pi/2. But my understanding of the step function is that it affects the y-axis, hence a step (up or down), and has nothing to do with the x-axis. Can you explain to me this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your understanding is right. In the definition you use $1(t)$ which is $1$ for $t \geq 0$ and $0$ for $t < 0$. When you write $1(t-a)$ this means it is shifted by $a$ in time, ie. it is $1$ for $t \geq a$ and $0$ for $t < a$.